# Dropdown value changes after postback in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have this piece of code and I can't figure out why Extended is never true.  When a user choose extended on the dropdown list something happens.  However when the page refreshes updates, the dropdown goes back to the default value of CURRENT.  Is there a way to make sure it stays on EXTENDED even after a page refresh or if I come back from a different page? Here is the query string after doing a certain task on the page:

/Queue/Queue.aspx?DrawingRequestId=376333&doQuerySearch=true&start=&end=&Ind=&Model=&status=Open&manager=&source=&assignee=&title=&features=&parts=&pas=&customer=&number=&project=&startIndex=1&endIndex=10&pageSize=10&total=202&date=EXTENDED&qsEnd=

```
public bool Extended
    {
        get
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["&date"] == "EXTENDED")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Tell this page to use the wide setting on the master page
        Master.UseWideSetting = true;

        //Check to see if the user has permission
        CheckPageForPermission("Queue");
        base.SetActiveMenuItem(3);

        ucPager.PageChange += new EDDC.Controls.Pager.EmptyEventHandler(ucPager_PageChange);

        GenerateSearchQueryString();

        List<CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole> roles = Common.GetCurrentUserRoles();


        foreach (CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole r in roles)
        {
            if (r.AddOnRole == "PUB")
            {
                bool exists = false;

                foreach (ListItem item in drpDateView.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Value == "Extended")
                    {
                        exists = true;

                    }
                    break;
                    if (!exists)
                    {
                        // Add the item if permissions are correct 
                        drpDateView.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Extended", "EXTENDED"));
                    }
                }
                if (Extended)
                {

                    LoadQueue("EXTENDED");

                }
                else
                {
                    LoadQueue("CURRENT");
                }
            }
        }


            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (AutoSearch)
                {
                    if (DrawingId != null)
                    {
                        AutoSearchPopulate();
                    }
                    /*------------------------------------------------------
                     * Bug 3209 Drawing Number Included
                     * 
                     * Resolution - Removed the Call to Populate the search.
                     * Also removed the Property for Drawing Number
                     * -----------------------------------------------------*/

                    qsSearch.Collapsed = false;

                    lblUsername.Text = Common.GetCurrentUserRec().ScreenName;
                    popupWindow.UpdatePanelToRefresh = upnlRequest.ClientID;

                    ResetPager();


                    //List<CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole> roles = Common.GetCurrentUserRoles();

                    drpDateView.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Extended", "Extended"));
                    drpDateView.SelectedValue = "EXTENDED";
                    LoadQueue("Extended");
                }
                else if (RefreshSearch)
                {
                    LoadSearchParameters();
                    LoadQueueFromQueryString();
                }
                else
                {
                    lblUsername.Text = Common.GetCurrentUserRec().ScreenName;
                    popupWindow.UpdatePanelToRefresh = upnlRequest.ClientID;

                    ResetPager();


                    //List<CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole> roles = Common.GetCurrentUserRoles();


                    foreach (CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole d in roles)
                    {
                        if (d.AddOnRole == "PUB")
                        {
                            drpDateView.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Extended", "EXTENDED"));

                        }
                    }


                    if (Extended)
                    {

                        LoadQueue("EXTENDED");

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LoadQueue("CURRENT");
                    }
                }


            }
        }
```

load queue takes the currently selected drpDateView.Item value and fills the page with the relevant data.

```
private void LoadQueue(string dateFilter)
{
LoadQueue(dateFilter, StartIndex, EndIndex, MaxResults);
}
```

Comment: where is LoadQueue? what does it do?

Comment: @wizpert I've added what dateview does.

Comment: still not sure what it does, plus first change the if (Request.QueryString["&date"] == "EXTENDED") to if (Request.QueryString["date"] == "EXTENDED") , you dont need to include the (&) in the query string

Comment: Hey I found out what was wrong in addition to &date.  I had the break in the wrong spot.  The loop was closing before it could iterate through the whole list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the for loop breaking in the wrong spot.  This seemed to fix my issue. I also had EXTENDED getting adding to the list more than necessary, so I removed the else statement which adds it if it isn't a postback.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Tell this page to use the wide setting on the master page
            Master.UseWideSetting = true;

```
        //Check to see if the user has permission
        CheckPageForPermission("Queue");
        base.SetActiveMenuItem(3);

        ucPager.PageChange += new EDDC.Controls.Pager.EmptyEventHandler(ucPager_PageChange);

        GenerateSearchQueryString();

        List<CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole> roles = Common.GetCurrentUserRoles();


        foreach (CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole r in roles)
        {
            if (r.AddOnRole == "PUB")
            {
                bool exists = false;

                foreach (ListItem item in drpDateView.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Value == "Extended")
                    {
                        exists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }


                if (!exists)
                {
                    // Add the item if permissions are correct 
                    drpDateView.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Extended", "EXTENDED"));
                }


                if (Extended)
                {

                    LoadQueue("EXTENDED");

                }
                else
                {
                    LoadQueue("CURRENT");
                }
            }
        }


        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (AutoSearch)
            {
                if (DrawingId != null)
                {
                    AutoSearchPopulate();
                }
                /*------------------------------------------------------
                 * Bug 3209 Drawing Number Included
                 * 
                 * Resolution - Removed the Call to Populate the search.
                 * Also removed the Property for Drawing Number
                 * -----------------------------------------------------*/

                qsSearch.Collapsed = false;

                lblUsername.Text = Common.GetCurrentUserRec().ScreenName;
                popupWindow.UpdatePanelToRefresh = upnlRequest.ClientID;

                ResetPager();


                //List<CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole> roles = Common.GetCurrentUserRoles();
                if (!drpDateView.Items.Contains(new ListItem("Extended", "Extended")))
                    drpDateView.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Extended", "Extended"));
                drpDateView.SelectedValue = "EXTENDED";
                LoadQueue("Extended");
            }
            else if (RefreshSearch)
            {
                LoadSearchParameters();
                LoadQueueFromQueryString();
            }
            else
            {
                lblUsername.Text = Common.GetCurrentUserRec().ScreenName;
                popupWindow.UpdatePanelToRefresh = upnlRequest.ClientID;

                ResetPager();


                //List<CAT.EDDC.Data.UserRole> roles = Common.GetCurrentUserRoles();


                if (Extended)
                {

                    LoadQueue("EXTENDED");

                }
                else
                {
                    LoadQueue("CURRENT");
                }
            }


        }
    }
```